# How to simulate commitEditingStyle data source method programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have table view I have override method commitEditingStyle: in which I am deleting the particular row. I have another button to do the same functionality. Is it possible to call the same commitEditingStyle: method so that I can reuse the code, or Do I need to write separate function to do that. But it will be replicated code then.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Don't pretend you're the table view. Instead, wrap your actual deletion code in a spearate function, and in the implementation of the true delegate method, call that one, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)s forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    if (s == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        [self deleteRowAtIndexPath:ip];
}

- (void)deleteRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    // put actual deletion code here
}
```

And then, when you want to 'simulate', simply call:

```
[self deleteRowAtIndexPath:anIndexPath];
```

Comment: I can pass index path from data source method. For my personal button click How do I get Index path?

Comment: @FerozMohideen I don't know it without any context.